What are these lines in the song "Poovukkul"?
In the song Poovukkul from the movie Jeans (1998), when the Empire State Building is shown, there is a chorus of "Je vous aime" ("I love you" in French) along with a line sounding like "jeau zang fi" (sorry if I transcribed it very badly).
Similarly, when the Pyramids of Giza are shown, there is a chorus of "ajooba ajooba" ("wonder" in Arabic) and something like "ooh aao imoki" (sorry if I transcribed it poorly once again). I want to know what these sentences sung in the chorus are which I am not able to understand.
I have searched about these on Google but couldn't find anything.

https://genius.com/Anirudh-vijay-poovukkul-olindhirukkum-cover-lyrics?

@Valorum it only has the main lyrics, not the ones I mentioned.

Please explain the downvote. I am new to asking questions on this site. Feedback would help me in publishing better quality questions in the future.

Some users hate these kinds of questions and blindly downvote them. I wouldn't worry too much about it.

@Valorum why would some users hate such questions?

We all have our petty likes and dislikes.
